# Can I have the template class' pointer as a parameter when declaring an object of that class' type in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is the code-version of the question:

```
   template <class T>
   class Foo
   {
       //Stuff
   }
   Foo<Foo*> object;
```

Compiling this gives me:

> "a template argument 1 is invalid error."

My question is,

- if it is possible to do the intended action above and if so, how and why does that said method work?
- If it isn't possible, I'm guessing it's because of having a circular reference inside the template parameter itself (e.g. `Foo<Foo<Foo<.....>>>` but please let me know the correct reason if I'm incorrect in my thinking.

Also I tried a forward declaration of `Foo`, and that did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Foo` need a template argument, you can:

```
Foo<Foo<int>*> object;
```

Comment: Ahh that's so simple and elegant. Thank you.